# Print two images on two full pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, printing

I try to print a simple html page that contains only two images. Each image needs to fill a full page. My testing images have the exact size of an A4 page 600 dpi.

This html page is printed from a hidden iframe. On Firefox it works well, meaning that I have each image on each page.
My issue is on chrome...a piece of the second image is on the third page for a reason... :(

```
<html>
<head><title>DoubleA4</title></head>
<body>
  <div style="position: absolute;  left: 0;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  right: 0;">
  <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/369262front.png">
  <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/143216back.png">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is a CSS issue but I have not been able to find a way to get a better render than this.

The demo that reproduce the issue: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0a83ymzz/5/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you display the images and their container as `block` elements, and remove all padding and margin around them, it should stop anything being bumped to the next page.

e.g.

```
var pages = '<html><head><title>DoubleA4</title></head><body>';
pages += '<div style="position: absolute;  left: 0;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  right: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">';
pages += '<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/369262front.png">';
pages += '<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/143216back.png">';
pages += '</div></body></html>';
```

Your JSFiddle modified with these changes:

https://jsfiddle.net/0a83ymzz/6/

Answer (score 0):

Give absolute position to both images instead of div because it's work for me i hope it's work for you too..

Comment: Please show with some code example as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).